# it is safe to delete content form /.trash folder?

Tags: shared-hosting

My shared hosting has /.trash folder with 2GB of files in it. 
Is it safe to delete that stuff?

I need to free up space.

Answer (score 0):

What type of account is it? Is it a windows or *NIX Based?

Either way I would say yes.